# #1064 error message

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

error when want to create table

MySQL said:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'mysql_query("CREATE TABLE " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "mssgs (
id mediumint(5) unsig' at line 1
```

---

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "mssgs (
      id mediumint(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      uid tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',

      m tinyint(2) NOT NULL default '0',
      d tinyint(2) NOT NULL default '0',
      y smallint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
      start_time time NOT NULL default '00:00:00',
      end_time time NOT NULL default '00:00:00',
      title varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
      text text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) TYPE=MyISAM") or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_query("create index m on " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "mssgs (m)");
    mysql_query("create index y on " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "mssgs (y)");

    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "users (
      uid smallint(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      username char(15) NOT NULL default '',
      password char(32) NOT NULL default '',
      fname char(20) NOT NULL default '',
      lname char(30) NOT NULL default '0',
      userlevel tinyint(2) NOT NULL default '0',
      email char(40) default NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (uid)
    ) TYPE=MyISAM") or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO " . DB_TABLE_PREFIX . "users 
        (username, password, fname, lname, userlevel, email) VALUES (
        'admin', 'password', 'default', 'user', 2, '');
    ")
```

Comment: Did you try to execute all of these SQL commands on MySQL (phpmyadmin) separately?

Comment: @Lion: Must be because error says syntax error near `mysql_query(` which isn't part of sql.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to execute the code above in phpadmin.

But this not is pure SQL. It is also PHP code and won't run in PHPAdmin.

You need to execute the code between the `"` and fill the gapes with values. Like that

```
CREATE TABLE mssgs (
  id mediumint(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  uid tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  m tinyint(2) NOT NULL default '0',
  d tinyint(2) NOT NULL default '0',
  y smallint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
  start_time time NOT NULL default '00:00:00',
  end_time time NOT NULL default '00:00:00',
  title varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  text text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: actually i make it in createtable.php...
when i follow your tips there new error come out

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 12

Comment: @JerungHidupKu: `TYPE` is deprecated. Replace it with `ENGINE`.

Comment: @JerungHidupKu: Click on the check symbol under the vote score of the answer.